# Creating a data frame with regression summary output and a correlation of actual/fitted values

Tags: r

I'm trying to evaluate a linear regression model and I'm struggling with how to combine elements of the summary output with a calculation based on fitted values. I want to split the dataset into training/test (63%/27%), train a model on the training set, fit the model to the test test, and calculate the correlation between the fitted values and the actual values of the test set. Then I want to repeat this process 1000 times, storing all coefficients, the model R2, and that correlation for each run.

The code below will calculate and put together everything I want for one run. I tried creating a function and using `replicate` to have it run 1000 times. I could get that to work for storing the coefficients and the model R2, but I couldn't figure out how to incorporate the correlation part. Pulling the coefficients and the model R2 from the lm summary is easy enough. And calculating the correlation for 270 fitted values and 270 actual values is easy enough. But I can't both of those results on one row in a way that will run 1000 times.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
library(caret)
data(GermanCredit)
#Split data into training test sets
sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(GermanCredit), size = floor(.63*nrow(GermanCredit)), replace = F)
train <- GermanCredit[sample, ]
test  <- GermanCredit[-sample, ]
#Create model
lr.mod<-lm(Amount~.,data=train)
lr.pred<-predict(lr.mod,newdata=test)
#Put results together
coef<-rbind(coef(lr.mod))
R2<-cbind(summary(lr.mod)$r.squared)
names(R2) <- "R2"
Fitted<-cbind(lr.pred)
R2test<-data.frame(cor(Fitted,test$Amount))
rownames(R2test)<-c()
names(R2test) <- "R2test"
final<-cbind(coef, R2,R2test)
```

Comment: check out [the broom package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) -- it's for exactly this kind of thing. you can ignore the "tidy" lingo and tangents in the link entirely. bottom line: it gets you nice rectangular summary info from fitted models.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll have to dig in further. Thanks!